# Estimating Cointegration vector

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, least-squares, cointegration

I am learning about the concept of cointegration and I found in various places the following claim about estimating the cointegration vector using OLS which is:
Despite the fact that the OLS estimator of cointegrated variables is super-consistent it is biased in finite samples.

My question is why is the OLS estimator biased in finite samples?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question, could you please link one of these sources?

Comment: In the following lecture: http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/finmath09/Cointegration.pdf   page 13

Answer (score 1):

It is not like it is necessarily biased. Consider this little simulation:

```
reps <- 10000
n <- 30

betahat <- rep(NA,reps)
for (i in 1:reps){
  u <- rnorm(n)
  x <- cumsum(rnorm(n))
  y <- 2*x + u
  betahat[i] <- summary(lm(y~x))$coefficients[2]
}
mean(betahat)
```

for which the bias is nonexistent. The distribution is also nicely normal:

[image]

Bias comes in when considering more general (one should/could also say: more realistic) cases: when the error terms driving `x` and the cointegration equation (here, `u`) are correlated and themselves exhibit short-run correlation. See e.g. the paper by [Gonzalo, JoE 1994](http://www.eco.uc3m.es/~jgonzalo/teaching/PhDTimeSeries/gonzalojec94.pdf) for a more thorough simulation, or Chapter 19 in Hamilton, "Time Series Analysis", for an asymptotic analysis.